# Children divs don't take up space inside parent div

Tags: css, html, footer

Hi this is my first time on this page.

Lets get straight to it, I have a website http://harrimanpcrepair.com/index.php and when you look at the footer with something like firebug you can see the div footer itself not the children doesn't show up specifically cause it has no height. Also the entire footer area including it's three children aren't part of my page div. Is there a way to fix this without hacks or anything please. last time I used overflow to fix this it caused some issues on my contact page. I've been looking and see all hacks to fix this I'm really not into hacking to get what I want but rather doing it how it's meant to be done with no hidden drawbacks that sneak up on you.

```
<div id="footer">

    <div id="footerLeft">&nbsp;</div>

    <div id="footerMiddle">Designed by Shawn Harriman</div>

    <div id="footerRight">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

I have though now decided to just force a height not realizing that it works if I do that though I hate knowing that the size doesn't affect the parent but I dont' really need it to due to the fact I don't like double lined footers. it's rare I'll ever have one so the way I have it now should work for now.  Would like to hear things people have to say though and other solutions please I am still looking to fix this with better means

EDIT: I didn't feel CSS in this was very neccessary but they are floating divs within footer. They all float left while they footer itself is clear: both. Having 3 does serve a later purpose.

Comment: Please provide code samples rather then requesting people to visit your pages. Using the latest opera I can see your name in the footer, middle div. The cleanest way to make it higher is by adding content, the div will grow along. One could also force a css height parameter on the children to force the surrounding div to grow along.

Comment: Ah excuse me, the parent div doesn't have a height because of the floating elements. You'll need a trick called clearfix: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: Dude, post some CSS as your post tells me nothing about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is that the actual markup of your footer? Why not just get rid of the children and apply a text-align:center? I don't know what you're actually intending to do with those &nbsp; divs but they currently serve no purpose unless they have some kind of defined css like a background or something

Comment: float problem? didn't specify yr height( since no contents )?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below css for your footer in main.css

```
  #footer {
     position:fixed; 
     text-align:center; 
     width:100%; 
     height:20px; 
     padding:5px; 
     bottom:0px; 
    }
```

Hope this helps